# Windows 10 Enterprise subscription is not valid

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-10, subscription

Recently i have one of our user's machine reverted itself from Windows 10 Enterprise to Pro

I have checked the requirements needed in order for Windows 10 Pro machine getting upgraded to Enterprise via M365 E3 license. I can verify that the machine is

1. AAD-Joined
2. Windows 10 1803
3. Valid M O365 E3 license assigned to the user

The current "error" i am getting is Windows 10 Pro activated with a digital license, Windows 10 Enterprise subscription is not valid.

[screenshot of "error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEh5e.png)

Not sure what else i need to check or do. Please help? Kind Regards

Comment: Any ideas guys? really need help with this

Comment: Does the user use another laptop computer joined to the AAD ?

Answer (score -1):

For me running the following command has solved this exact issue:

`cscript.exe c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /ipk AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD-EEEEE-FFFFF`

As seen in: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-10-enterprise-subscription-activation

Comment: AAD joined machines do get their activation from the AAD licensing. Did you assign a Windows Enterprise License to the user/device?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. the device have our Win 10 Pro volume licenses applied. Conversion from Pro to Ent is done via M365 E3 license via the O365 portal

Comment: What i have been doing so far for these problem devices is dis-join and re-join them to the domain. After that manually sync our local AD to AAD and wait for the device to be shown as registered in AAD